How to recall terms from all search methods?
vim have many things that the manual describe just as "search forward".
1. Search commands                               search-commands 

                                                         / 
/{pattern}[/]<CR>       Search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of
                        {pattern} |exclusive|.                      

[...]
                                                         star   E348   E349 
*                       Search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of the
                        word nearest to the cursor.  The word used for the

Yet, only the ones entered with the / command will show up on the command history.
How can i have all the other "search" commands (*, #, g*, gd, etc) be part of a common history pool?
For example, let's say i am in a .c file. I press * a few times to search some terms. Then I open the .h file... now I can only search for the last term by pression n and there's no way to search for the previous ones I have just searched for! if i have searched then by using /, then when moving files i could use /<UP> and search for them again.

Wait a second, I can * a word and then do /<up> and make it show up.

All the actions you mention (/, *, #, g*) populate the search history.
You can navigate the search history using:

/Ctrl+p and /Ctrl+n
/Up and /Down or using
q/


Only the last one is present on history. If you add two terms ("one", then "two") via *, only "two" will be in the history. "one" will not be in history at all.

This is not what I observe on my 9.1 version of gVim :-| Could you share your version number (:version)? Could you share the result of the q/ command?

vivan, and Friedrich, you are correct. I do get the history just fine with q/ but not with /<up>... i might have something fiddling with that. So it's a user problem and the history is there just fine. ...i also misunderstood the help text. assumed "mapping" to mean things in commands in Normal mode.

Thanks for your feedback. I indeed believe that the mapping is not related. I suspect it is related to the behavior of the command triggered by a map family of command (that must be very fast). I confirm I have the full history with /<Up> and /<Down>. something odd seems to appear on your end. If you slightly update the search string <Up> and <Down> restrict themselves to search with the same prefix. Maybe could you try <C-p> and <C-n> that navigate the history without taking into account the actual content of the search buffer.

from :help history
                                                 cmdline-history   history 
The command-lines that you enter are remembered in a history table.  You can
recall them with the up and down cursor keys.  There are actually five
history tables:
- one for ':' commands
- one for search strings
[...]
Notes:
[...]
- All searches are put in the search history, including the ones that come
  from commands like "*" and "#".  But for a mapping, only the last search is
  remembered (to avoid that long mappings trash the history).

So, I am guessing the answer is no. :(
